# How do I lock user permissions for a shared item on a page without it throwing a runtime error for a user that does not have permissions to that item?

Tags: permissions, editor-user-permissions

Fairly new to Sitecore (10.1.3) and trying to add role permissions to snippets in the shared data folder. Made it so only certain roles would have the ability to fully edit a snippet item, all others would have read access. Here's the issue I'm trying to troubleshoot....

If I have a page in which my role gives me read/write permissions on, that contains a snippet item that I only have read permission restrictions for, when I try to do a check-in it trips a try/catch error (Content Editor shows a runtime error, Experience Editor shows an error ribbon). However, if I navigate away and back it puts itself in the right state and shows my changes.

I've tried to search for a solution to be able to restrict an item on a page but not trip this error. Has anyone come across this and how did you resolve?

Comment: Can you check the logs what errors you are getting. Also, try sharing snapshot of errors you get. Also, if you only have read access only on an item, you shall not be able to make any changes on it. It seems there is some issue in they way security rules are configured.

Answer (score 0):

Ghanendra, thanks for responding! After I posted I took a step back regarding the situation and realized it was an issue with not explicitly denying read rights to the roles that I did not want to edit snippets. After doing that, no more error messages.